# Select rows with multiple values in columns and compare value in different column

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have researched this a ton, but I cannot find the answer to the issue I am having. I have a table that has four columns like so:

```
+------+------+------+------+
|ID    |LOAD  |STOP  |A/D/AD|
+------+------+------+------+
|1     |A     |1     |A     |
+------+------+------+------+
|2     |B     |2     |AD    |
+------+------+------+------+
|3     |C     |1     |D     |
+------+------+------+------+
|4     |A     |1     |D     |
+------+------+------+------+
|5     |D     |2     |AD    |
+------+------+------+------+
|6     |C     |2     |A     |
+------+------+------+------+
|7     |C     |2     |D     |
+------+------+------+------+
|8     |E     |1     |A     |
+------+------+------+------+
|9     |F     |2     |D     |
+------+------+------+------+
|10    |G     |1     |A     |
+------+------+------+------+
```

From this, I am needing to retrieve all load and stop numbers that do not have an AD or an A and D in the A/D/AD column. To clarify further, I want to look at each individual load and look at its stop number then see if there are any other appearances in the table with those values. Then I want to see what the values are and only return the entry if it does not have AD in the A/D/AD column or two entries that have both an A and a D. So my results should be this:

```
+------+------+------+------+
|ID    |LOAD  |STOP  |A/D/AD|
+------+------+------+------+
|3     |C     |1     |D     |
+------+------+------+------+
|8     |E     |1     |A     |
+------+------+------+------+
|9     |F     |2     |D     |
+------+------+------+------+
|10    |G     |1     |A     |
+------+------+------+------+
```

So to expand on the results, we can look at Load C and see that it appears multiple times, but Load C, Stop 1 only appears once. Load C, Stop 1 has a value of D only in the A/D/AD column and thus it is returned. I have tried multiple solutions involving case statements, but this does not appear to be quite what I am needing. I have looked into using unions on itself, but I am unable to do that as they might return different number of rows. I am just completely stuck on how to implement the necessary logic to accomplish my goal. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are number of approaches. The natural or simplistic approach is to check existence using sub-queries (in your case matching on both `Load` and `Stop` columns). And if you break the entire job down in small chunks, each chunk can be combined into the final output using `UNION`. So the 'first principal' approach to your question would be:

```
select  Id, Load, Stop, A_D_AD
from    Table a
where   A_D_AD = 'A'
    and not exists (
        select  *
        from    Table d
        where   d.Load = a.Load
            and d.Stop = a.Stop
            and d.A_D_AD = 'D'
union all
select  ... 
/* Similar query for rows where A_D_AD = 'D' but 
   matches for A_D_AD = 'A' do not exist.  */
```

However, in some cases you may be able to leverage a better understanding of the input data. E.g. If in your case the following is true:

- any 'A' row for a given `Load/Stop` pair
- never has an 'AD' row,
- never has a second 'A' row,
- and only has 0 or 1 'D' rows.
- and similar for 'D' rows for a give `Load/Stop` pair.

Then you could easily find `Load/Stop` pairs that you want to return using a simple counting query:

```
select  Load, Stop
from    Table t
where   t.A_D_AD in ('A', 'D')
group by Load, Stop
having  count(*) = 1 /* Guarantees either A without D or vice-versa*/
```

Joining these results back to the base table yields all columns (demonstrated in next example).

Finally, in some more complicated scenarios you may find it easier to:

- pivot your data into a summary of the values you're *interested in*;
- filter according to your rules;
- and join back to source data

For example:

```
select  Id, Load, Stop, A_D_AD
from    (
        select  *
        from    (
                select  Load, Stop,
                        sum(case A_D_AD when 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as A_Count,
                        sum(case A_D_AD when 'D' then 1 else 0 end) as D_Count,
                        sum(case A_D_AD when 'AD' then 1 else 0 end) as AD_Count
                from    Table
                group by Load, Stop
                ) pvt /* Pivoted to count the rows for each A/D/AD value */

        where   pvt.AD_Count = 0
            or  (pvt.A_Count = 0 and pvt.D_Count = 0)
        ) f /* The Stop/Load rows to return */
        inner join Table src /* Join back to source data */
          on  src.Stop = f.Stop
          and src.Load = f.Load
```